# Problemas con graphql rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

Hola actualmente estoy creando la mutacion para hacer login con un user registrado, pero al momento de configurar mi mutation y correrla me aparece el siguiente error

> "message": "key must be 32 bytes"

El codigo para la configuracion del registro de usuario es el siguiente:

```
class Mutations::SignInUser < Mutations::BaseMutation
argument :email, Types::AuthProviderEmailInput, required: false

field :token, String, null: true
field :user, Types::UserType, null: true

def resolve(email: nil)
    #basic validation
    return unless email

    user = User.find_by email: email[:email]
    return unless user
    return unless user.authenticate(email[:password])

    # use Ruby on Rails - ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor, to build a token
    crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base(0..32))
    token = crypt.encrypt_and_sign("user-id:#{ user.id }")

    { user: user, token: token }
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, estuve leyendo mejor la documentacion y me habia saltado un metodo que toma un rango de 0 a 31 -> ***byteslice***

```
class Mutations::SignInUser < Mutations::BaseMutation
argument :email, Types::AuthProviderEmailInput, required: false

field :token, String, null: true
field :user, Types::UserType, null: true

def resolve(email: nil)
#basic validation
return unless email

user = User.find_by email: email[:email]
return unless user
return unless user.authenticate(email[:password])

# use Ruby on Rails - ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor, to build a token
crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base.byteslice(0..32))
token = crypt.encrypt_and_sign("user-id:#{ user.id }")

{ user: user, token: token }
end
end
```